# Pyephem Alt. and Az are completely wrong

Tags: python, python-2.7, astronomy, pyephem

I'm getting completely incorrect values for altitude and azimuth of the sun when calculated using the pyephem library.

I've already established my observer location, which is determined by `raw_input` for the lat and lon. I've checked to make sure this input is appropriate, and it is.

I have a bit of code in a `for` loop that adds the altitude and azimuth of the sun to my list, DataPoint:

```
TempTime = str(DataPoint)[2:28] #strange date/time format. this fixes it
observer.date = TempTime
SunData = ep.Sun(observer)
DataPoint.append(SunData.alt)
DataPoint.append(SunData.az)
```

so, while this should work, [this](http://aa.usno.navy.mil/data/docs/AltAz.php) website calculates different values for my date/time and location.

If someone could help me figure out what I'm doing wrong, that'd be great.

Comment: keep in mind that pyephem [takes refraction into account](http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/tutorial.html#computations-for-particular-observers).

Comment: @paintedcones Yeah, I have. ephem will say alt/az is -32/47 when it should be 76/276 respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pyephem isn't wrong, your TempTime stripping method is wrong. Note this code from pyephem's tutorial:

```
gatech.date = '1984/5/30 16:22:56'   # 12:22:56 EDT
```

When setting the time for an observer, you need to use GMT, not EST, EDT, CST, etc etc. Since you're getting an altitude of BELOW the horizon on the eastern side, pyephem is assuming that you're passing it a morning GMT time, which will lead to a pre-sunrise EDT (or whatever presumably American timezone you're using.).